# Send certain welcome message after subscription to certain mailing list

Tags: groups, mailing, system-workflow-messages

I think this is an obvious feature, but I can't find it anywhere.

I can set several custom "Welcome" Automated Messages but I would like to be able to assign certain custom "Welcome" automated messages to be sent after a user signs up for a certain mailing list.

For example:

User signs up for mailing list "dogs" and in the body message (sent after successfully double opt-in) is "Thanks for subscribing to Dogs!". But if the user subscribes to "cats" the message is sent containing "cats" in body text.

I've tried using CiviRules, but Civirules is not respecting double opt -in. It sends e-mail even if user won't confirm subscription.

Has anyone figured it out?

Comment: How many different welcome messages/groups are there? If only a few you might be able to use scheduled reminders and limit the recipients to that particular group and have the wording set as necessary in the actual email text?

Comment: It isn't working as it sends this email right after user subscribes (even before he double opts in)

Comment: Oh. Thanks for pointing that out. I assumed that it would factor in the group status at that stage

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried using CiviRules, but Civirules is not respecting double opt -in. It sends e-mail even if user won't confirm subscription.

Try adding a Linked Condition of Field Value Comparison:

- Entity: GroupContact
- Field: Group Contact Status
- Operator: Is equal to
- Compare Value: Added